# Want to create some dataset based on a varibale in SAS

Tags: sas

I am very new to SAS. I have written code to do some data manipulation in SAS. The challenge is that every time before 
executing this piece of code, I must manually change the name of datasets. Which took lot of time. There is some pattern in naming convention.
Suppose my dataset name is XXX_IN_MUM_Dec_2016. So, before executing I have change the name to XXX_IN_MUM_Jan_2017

Sample Code:

```
data XXX_IN_MUM_Dec_2016;
set XXX_IN_MUM_Dec_2016;
FILENAME_MONTH=input(CATS(strip("01"),SCAN(strip(filename_BILL),4,"_")),anydtdte.);
format FILENAME_MONTH monyy7.;
if intnx('month','1SEP2016'd,0,'b'). <= FILENAME_MONTH <= intnx('month','1FEB2017'd,0,'e') then output;
run;
```

In above code, I want to pass a variable instead of dataset name (XXX_IN_MUM_Jan_2017).

Thanks
Mohd Shams

Comment: Do you also want to change the date range used in the `IF` statement?

Comment: Yes...in most cases

Comment: So update the question to reflect what you really need.  What date value do you have? Today's date? Something else?  What dates do you need it converted into?  What format do you need the dates converted into to match how the files/datasets are named?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you start a SAS session system macro variable SYSDATE is automatically created. It displays a two-digit date, the first three letters of the month name, and a two-digit year. So you can use it:

```
%let month = %substr(&sysdate, 3, 3);
%let year = %substr(&sysdate, 6, 2);
%put &month &year;

data XXX_IN_MUM_&month._20&year;
    set XXX_IN_MUM_&month._20&year;
    /* your code*/
run;
```

Today the dataset name resolved to XXX_IN_MUM_mar_2017.